# Gradient approaching to zero

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Either prove or disprove  by counterexample-
Let $f:R^n\to R$ such that $f$ is differentiable on $R^n-\text{{0}}$ , $f$ is continuous at $0$ and $\lim_{x\to 0} \nabla f = 0$ , then show that $f$ is differentiable at $0$. Actually for single dimensional case I can prove it's true by mean value theorem but I don't feel like it's true for $n>1$ but still can't find a counterexample yet. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Let  $h \in \mathbb R^n, h \ne 0$. By the mean value theorem for functions with $n$ variables, there is $z(h) \in \{th: t \in [0,1]\}$ such that

$$f(h)-f(0) = h \cdot \nabla f(z(h)).$$

By Cauchy - Schwarz

$$|f(h)-f(0)| \le  ||h|| \cdot ||\nabla f(z(h))||$$

Hence

$$\frac{|f(h)-f(0)|}{||h||} \le ||\nabla f(z(h))||.$$

This shows that

$$\frac{|f(h)-f(0)|}{||h||} \to 0$$

as $h \to 0$. This means that $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and $f'(0)=0.$

Answer (score 0):

Fix $ \epsilon > 0 $; by hypothesis there exists a $ \delta > 0 $ such that $ \| \nabla f (w) \| \le \epsilon $ whenever $\|w\|\le \delta$. So by the Mean Value Theorem $$ \|f(w) - f(0) \| \le \|\nabla f (t w) \| \|w\|\le \epsilon \|w\|, \quad t \in (0,1) $$which implies the differentiability of $f$ at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

With the one-dimensional case plus $\nabla_xf\stackrel{x\to 0}\longrightarrow 0$ you can prove that the partial derivatives exist at $0$ and that they are all $0$. Thus, you have proved that the partial derivatives exist in a neighbourhood of $0$ and that they're continuous at $0$. This implies differentiability at zero (this is sometimes called the "total differential theorem", though some authors refer to it with the unnecessary hypothesis that the partial derivatives should be continuous in a neighbourhood of the point of interest, instead of the single point).